# My iPhone was stolen a while ago

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

So my iPhone was stolen a while ago, but today I have received an email from Apple saying it has been located. I signed into my iCloud account, but my iPhone does not show up. I am not sure on what to do. If someone could help me get my iPhone back, that would be greatly appreciated.
Please and Thank You

Comment: Were there any instructions to follow in in the email?

Comment: no unfortunately there was not. All it said was too log into my icloud account to find the precise location of my phone.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone was likely turned on only very briefly. Consequently, when you logged in and iCloud requested its location, it was unavailable. If the antennas booted up you would have been fortunate enough to get a "last known location", I believe.

As it is, all you can do is log into iCloud and make sure your stolen iPhone is still registered as "lost" and pray.